# get executed url from another source url

Tags: c#

I have a url1:
`https://auth.mercadolivre.com.br/authorization?response_type=code&client_id=999999999999&redirect_uri=http%3a%2f%2flocalhost`

When I paste it into a browser, it should redirect to url2:
`http://localhost/?code=TG-9999999999999999-888888`

It happens when done manually!

However, when trying in C#, it redirects to
`https://www.mercadolivre.com/jms/mlb/lgz/login/?go=https%3A%2F%2Fauth.mercadolivre.com.br%2Fauthorization%3Fclient_id%999999999999%26redirect_uri%3Dhttp%253A%252F%252Flocalhost%26response_type%3Dcode&platform_id=ml&application_id=999999999999` as opposed to `http://localhost/?code=TG-9999999999999999-888888`.

14/5000
See the code:

```cs
public static string GrtUrl(string url)
{
    Uri ourUri = new Uri(url);

    // Create a 'WebRequest' object with the specified url. 
    WebRequest myWebRequest = WebRequest.Create(url);

    // Send the 'WebRequest' and wait for response.
    WebResponse myWebResponse = myWebRequest.GetResponse();

    // Use "ResponseUri" property to get the actual Uri from where the response was attained.
    if (ourUri.Equals(myWebResponse.ResponseUri))
        Console.WriteLine("\nRequest Url : {0} was not redirected", url);
    else
        Console.WriteLine("\nRequest Url : {0} was redirected to {1}", url, myWebResponse.ResponseUri);
    // Release resources of response object.
    myWebResponse.Close();
    return myWebResponse.ResponseUri.ToString();
}
```

Comment: You are logged in to the website in your browser, and you are not sending the authorization information with the C# request?

Comment: can you please tell me what exactly you wants to do?

Comment: 409/5000
pasting url 1 directly into the browser, I'm redirecting to url 2, where I get the http: // localhost /? code = TG-9999999999999999-888888 and I need the code every time I perform an operation on the system.
I am not logged into the system to paste url 1 and be redirected to url 2.
what i really need is for this procedure to be automatic so that the system does this routine that today is manual.
thanks!

Comment: I need the updated code=TG-9999999999999999-888888  return in secund url redirected for the complete my authorization information.